# db_recovery_file_dest_size issue

Tags: oracle-11g, rman

RMAN gives me this error how should i resolve this issue:

```
    ORA-19815: WARNING: db_recovery_file_dest_size of 7516192768 bytes is 100.00 used, and has 0 remaining bytes available.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As the warning says, the recovery area is full. You don't say if this is located on a file system or perhaps in ASM, but a typical solution would be to delete some old archive logs or backup sets.

Comment: can you show us the output of `SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;` and `SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_AREA_USAGE`? `SELECT NAME FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;` returns the name of the directory of the recovery file area. Can you show us the size of the disk/filesystem of the fast recovery area (e.g. by `df -k fast_recovery_area_directory` if it is a unix system)? It also would be useful to show the output of the command `SHOW RETENTION POLICY;` in rman.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Oracle's answer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmmaint.htm#BRADV89615).

Basically your options are these:

- [Delete transient files no longer needed for current policies.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta016.htm#RCMRF121)
- [Change something stored in the Fast Recovery Area to be stored elsewhere](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmconfb.htm#CHDIBECI) This could be temporarily or permanently.
- [Increase the db_recovery_file_dest_size to be larger than 7 GB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams066.htm#REFRN10235).
- [Decrease your backup window or redundancy.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmconfb.htm#i1019318)
- [Change your archivelog retention policy.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmconfb.htm#CHDCFHBG)
- [Drop guarenteed restore points.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/flashdb.htm#CFHFIHAA)

Comment: +1 but it makes sense to check first which files allocate how much space in the fast recovery area by checking the output of `SELECT * FROM   V$RECOVERY_AREA_USAGE`

Comment: @miracle173 Good tip.